# IMX6ULL: [ 75.326643] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop! on Linux 6.1.1

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bootloader, device-tree, imx6

- i.MX6ULL Processor: **MCIMX6Y2CVM08AB**
- Kernal version: **6.1.1**

I'm currently working on an **IMX6ULL processor** - based custom System on Module (SOM) inside an **evaluation board** (EVB).

I'm encountering an issue with the **watchdog configuration in the device tree source (dts) file**. Our board (EVB) has the **RESET SWITCH pin assigned to the LCD_RESET pin**, and in the dts file, the watchdog is initialized as follows:

watchdog1 node:

```
&wdog1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_wdog>;
    fsl,ext-reset-output;
    status = "okay";
};
```

pinmux (signal name with address) :

```
pinctrl_wdog: wdoggrp {
        fsl,pins = <
            MX6UL_PAD_LCD_RESET__WDOG1_WDOG_ANY    0x30b0
        >;
    };
```

After compiling the dts file, I copied the .dtb file onto an **SD card** and inserted it into the evaluation board (EVB). When attempting to reboot using the command `sudo reboot` in the minicom console, the following result is displayed:

```
[   75.326643] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
[   75.454057] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[   75.466793] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[   75.500037] systemd-journald[136]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[   75.533967] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[   75.580073] systemd-shutdown[1]: Using hardware watchdog 'imx2+ watchdog', version 0, device /dev/watchdog
[   75.613192] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[   75.629645] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[   75.641787] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[   75.652640] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[   75.663915] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[   75.701770] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[   75.714008] systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices.
[   75.726478] systemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped.
[   75.737972] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[   75.750480] systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
[   75.762128] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems, swaps, loop devices, MD devices and DM devices detached.
[   75.791880] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[   75.802564] systemd-shutdown[1]: Rebooting.
[   75.820672] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.1: remove, state 4
[   75.825248] usb usb1: USB disconnect, device number 1
[   75.832068] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.1: USB bus 1 deregistered
[   75.852437] imx2-wdt 20bc000.watchdog: Device shutdown: Expect reboot!
[   75.860581] reboot: Restarting system
```

also I've referred to https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/iMX6ULL-Watchdog-2-does-not-reset-system-on-Linux-5-4/t... but still encounter the same issue. Specifically.

`[   75.326643] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!`

Could you kindly guide me on **How to reboot the board with or without assigning the external pin for the watchdog node in the dts file? Also, Is there any soft mode method to trigger the watchdog for the reset switch on the board?**

Comment: Do you experience any issues other than a message on the console?

Comment: No, while reboot board on the console with ```sudo reboot``` commond, i've have only issue with above console statement.

Comment: Then what's the problem? If you want to stop watchdog, issue respective IOCTL (there is watchdog daemon usually available in the system which can do whatever you want to).

Comment: Actually in our hardware Carrier Board, There is no usage external pin for reset switch so How to trigger that reset switch without declaring the external pin in the software mode (dts file)? & How to hold the reset switch for specific duration?


I hope you understood my point.

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add @USER to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: Your comment hadn't shed a light to me. Try to update your Q with the necessary details to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.